# How do I use a per request global variable for NLog in .net core?

Tags: nlog

I found this, but this seems to be for asp.net mvc (not .net core):
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetItem-layout-renderer

See HttpContext.Items:
https://odetocode.com/articles/111.aspx

Comment: `HttpContext.Items` also exist for AspNet.Core. See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.items and https://www.carlrippon.com/httpcontext-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Alternative you can use ILogger.BeginScope. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging#beginscope